# Apache Spark: get elements of Row by name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, dataframe

In a `DataFrame` object in Apache Spark (I'm using the Scala interface), if I'm iterating over its `Row` objects, is there any way to extract values by name?  I can see how to do some really awkward stuff:

```
def foo(r: Row) = {
  val ix = (0 until r.schema.length).map( i => r.schema(i).name -> i).toMap
  val field1 = r.getString(ix("field1"))
  val field2 = r.getLong(ix("field2"))
  ...
}
dataframe.map(foo)
```

I figure there must be a better way - this is pretty verbose, it requires creating this extra structure, and it also requires knowing the types explicitly, which if incorrect, will produce a runtime exception rather than a compile-time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported at this time in the Scala API. The closest you have is [this JIRA titled "Support converting DataFrames to typed RDDs"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7160)

Answer (score 39):

You can use "`getAs`" from `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

```
r.getAs("field1")
r.getAs("field2")
```

Know more about [getAs(java.lang.String fieldName)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#getAs%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I think it should be
r.getAs[Any]("fieldName")